# New gitlab instance is refusing to allow pushes

Tags: git, gitlab

Installed gitlab, and the web interface, and logging indicate things are up and running. However, when I try to push a new repo to it, it fails with (for http):

```
[gerry@boundary ct12Logger]$ git push -u origin master --verbose
Pushing to http://aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov:8080/gerry/ct12-logging.git
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized while accessing http://aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov:8080/gerry/ct12-logging.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Similarly, with an ssh attempt...

```
[gerry@boundary ct12Logger]$ git remote rm origin
[gerry@boundary ct12Logger]$ git remote add origin git@aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov:gerry/ct12-logging.git
[gerry@boundary ct12Logger]$ git push -u origin master --verbose
Pushing to git@aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov:gerry/ct12-logging.git
Access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is all installed on  RHEL 6.4 system. A status request claims sidekiq and gitlab are running appropriately. I'm at a dead end and would appreciate some ideas I can try.

Another datapoint: Although I've set my username as appropriate, when I do the following,

```
ssh -T  git@aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov
```

I get the following:

```
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
```

This suggests to me that git isn't appropriately finding the username...

Comment: Have you granted permissions to the user you are pushing as, for the bare repo on `gitlab`? Have you registered this users `ssh-key` with `gitlab`?

Comment: Um... I think so. I had tried to do a non-global user.name change to 'gerry' who DOES have access, and the full user name is also in there.  I suspect there's a trivial issue I've missed, but I lack the experience to sort that out right now! 

THanks!

Comment: Just tried 'ssh git@aaaa' and I got: 
    PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
     Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
                             Connection to aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov closed.

My current premise is something's not right with usernames?

Comment: And, ssh keys are all registered with gitlab.

Comment: If this is a fresh installation, I honestly recommend moving to `ubuntu`. I moved from RHEL to Ubuntu after a few months. It is not worth all the effort it takes to debug and fix things, with a new release coming out every month. `gitlab` folks are in love with `ubuntu` (at least that is true so far).

Comment: I'm "policy-bound" to RHEL. I considered changing, since the GitLab recommendation is debian (or a similarly derived distro) but I was told "No." 

I am fairly sure I've missed something basic. Hoping wiser/more experienced eyes will see an obvious indicator, and guide me that way.

Comment: If you never figure this out, Atlassian Stash is quite nice.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A very good article to achieve it by installing the new git version on the Centos.

http://www.storelocatorplus.com/update-git-on-centos-6-3/

It resolves the problem on my side.

Comment: Link is 404 now.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** You may want to mask the real domain name that appears in the error message you have posted.

**Now try these:**

Since `ssh -T git@aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov` is identifying you as `Anonymous`, try

```
ssh -i /path/to/private/key -T  git@aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov
```

If this works, then add the following lines to `$HOME/.ssh/config` on your local machine

```
Host *
   StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov
   User git
   IdentityFile /path/to/private/key
   Port 22
```

now try again

```
 ssh -T git@aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov
```

You can add a `v` switch to the `ssh` command for verbose output, like this

```
 ssh -Tvv git@aaaa.bbbb.cccc.gov
```

(you can use more `v`s for more verbose output). This will be useful in trouble shooting `ssh` related issues

Hopefully this should work. If it fails, then most likely the public key you have registered with `gitlab` does not match with the private key you are using.

### Update:

Just came across this link. You may find this useful: [Installing GitLab on RedHat Enterprise 5](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/general/installing-gitlab-on-redhat-enterprise-5-rhel-5.html)

Comment: What's the point of masking the domain name now? Once it's posted to Stack Overflow it's [available perpetually](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/fa6588f2-8314-4606-8552-7390093e907f/view-source) unless a moderate obliterates the answer.

Comment: I had tried to mask it; one slipped through. Thanks for spotting it. I'll take some steps.

Comment: I've been looking at a variety of suggestions, Following the instructions for creating a new key-pair, I've removed the offenders from the gitlab instance by means fo the gui... and discovered that, perhaps, keys are not going where they belong. Any idea of where I should be looking? ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys?

Comment: look for the value of `auth_file:` in `/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml`. It points to the file in which the authorized keys are stored by `GitLab`

Answer (score 0):

It helps to check your own work. I'm using Apache2, known in RHEL as httpd. I had made all the neceessary tweaks in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf but I'd missed some in /etc/httpd/conf.d/gitlab.conf. I was using the wrong proxy ports in that file, and since it's read AFTER httpd.conf, it was changing the proxy port settings.

It's working. Tested. Gotta get it tested by another couple of colleagues, then it's good.

Thanks all, for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be a version with git.

I removed the 1.7.10 Version and installed 1.7.12.

It's working. Tested.

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/solved-401-unauthorized-with-http-push/190